# OpenCV Aborted (core dumped) When the Window Is Closed

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.2

I try to read a camera frame and show it through `cv::namedWindow` using `cv::cuda::GpuMat`.

Here is my C++ code:

```
cv::namedWindow("frame", cv::WINDOW_OPENGL);
cv::resizeWindow("frame", FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
while (true) {
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::cuda::GpuMat frame_gpu;

    camera.read(frame);
    frame_gpu.upload(frame);

    cv::imshow("frame", frame_gpu);

    //frame_gpu.download(frame);

    if (cv::waitKey(1) == 27) {
        break;
    }
}
cv::destroyAllWindows();
```

If I close the window I got this error:

```
OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (You should explicitly call download method for cuda::GpuMat object) in getMat_, file /home/nvidia/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1276
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /home/nvidia/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:1276: error: (-213) You should explicitly call download method for cuda::GpuMat object in function getMat_

Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I type `Esc` key to end the logic, it does not raise any exception.

Why do I get this error and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error is about you trying to display `GpuMat` image using imshow. You need to download it to another `Mat` before you can display it using imshow. 
Try this

```
cv::Mat host;
frame_gpu.upload(frame);
frame_gpu.download(host)
cv::imshow("frame", host);
```

Comment: Then isn't there any advantage to use `cv::cuda::GpuMat`?

Comment: What kind of advantage do you expect from using GpuMat the way you do?

Comment: @GyuHyeon Choi you see the advantage processing a GpuMat on GPU. What you are doing is copying the Mat from CPU to GPU and vice-versa and nothing else. Maybe try reading what GPU does actually. http://opencv.org/platforms/cuda.html

Comment: Uh... I omitted other parts of code to make it more readable. There are multiple things to do with GPU so I thought it would be better to pass `GpuMat` to `imshow` if `GpuMat.download` is a bit expensive?

Comment: yes! it is expensive. Uploading and downloading from CPU to GPU takes time.